# Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction server Failed

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

what is the purpose of **Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction server**, I am asking this because I tried installing ODTwithODAC (Oracle) on a server and i got the error message **Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server Failed**

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions on stackoverflow. It doesn't look like you're having a specific problem/issue to be solved nor did you show any effort in answering the question on your own.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear with my thoughts when I posted this question. I was having issues installing Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio on a clients sever. All the required services were installed successfully except "Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction server", so i was wondering the effect of the installation failing at that point as the issue seemed to be peculiar to that particular server, because I was able to successfully install it on another server.